# laravel return view::make not working

Tags: jquery, laravel-4

I am having a brain melt over something seemingly simple.
I am using ajax to upload images to this code

```
foreach(Input::file('image') as $image){

        $imagename = $image->getClientOriginalName();

        $uploadflag = $image->move('public/uploads', $imagename);

        $urlPath = 'uploads/';

        $showPath = $urlPath . $imagename;

        if($uploadflag){

            $uploadedImages[] = $showPath;
        }
    }
    return View::make('index')
        ->with('uploadedImages', $uploadedImages);
```

The target page is index.blade.php which contains

```
@foreach($uploadedImages as $uploadedImage)

 {{ HTML::image($uploadedImage) }}

@endforeach
```

In Chrome DevTools Network Preview/Response I can see the images on the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">


           <img src="http://localhost:8000/uploads/3.jpg">


           <img src="http://localhost:8000/uploads/4.jpg">


        </div>

    </div>
```

But the page doesn't load in the browser, it stays on the upload form page.
If I remove the jQuery....

```
<script>
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formdata = new FormData(form);
    request.open('post', 'submit', true);
    request.send(formdata);

}, false);

</script>
```

....then it works.So what is going on with the jQuery that stops the return View::make working and what can I do to get it to work?

UPDATED
These are some of the variations I have tried - ajaxindex is the id of the container div in index.blade.php

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  $( "#ajaxindex" ).append( data );
});

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  $( "#ajaxindex" ).append( $uploadedImages );
});

$.ajax( "index", function( data ) {
  $( "#ajaxindex" ).append( data );
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You are submitting the form via Ajax and clearly you're getting the right response back via Ajax. You cannot submit via Ajax and expect a redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your greeting! So that's the cause of the problem but how do I get the data into a view to display it?

Comment: Since you're receiving the data back via ajax, you can manipulate the content of the current page to show the response from the server ... you have it ---> just display it ... `$('.some-selector').append( data );` Feel free to use `$.ajax()` or `$.post()`.

Comment: PeterKA, thanks for your help, I am not sure how to use the suggested $('.some-selector').append( data );

Comment: PeterKA last comment got truncated somehow - anyway I have tried to apply this but without success. I need to get the $uploadedImages data into the index.blade.php as you know but Laravel gives errors of undefined variable uploadedImages when I try. Could you please tell me what to put and where to put it, thanks. Please see updated info above

Answer (score 0):

Add the following markup to `index.blade.php`:

```
<div id="uploaded_images"></div>
```

Then use the following JavaScript/jQuery in place of the JavaScript you posted:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formdata = new FormData();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formdata,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            processData: false, 
            contentType: false, 
            success: function( data ) {
                $('#uploaded_images').html( data );
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi PeterKA, thanks for this. I still get Undefined variable: uploadedImages from laravel. The code above is designed to output data to a div but I wanted to output data that the php foreach Input::file('image' as $image) could receive and manipulate. Is what I seek not doable using Ajax with php? I seem to be so near yet so far it's really frustrating. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry that comment was rambling. I can already get data from the Ajax to the php and put the data into the uploadImage @foreach loop. The problem I have is that I then cannot display the page. As I said DevTools shows the images in the page but woe is me that I am stuck there.

Comment: ***You cannot submit via Ajax and expect a redirect.*** Do you need clarification on this statement?